# Stack Overflow Error while generating PDF using jira-javamelody-1.57.1.jar

Tags: java, itext

```
class ProductRequestPage2 extends PdfPageEventHelper

public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {}

Table table = new Table(1);table.setWidth(100);
table.setTableFitsPage(true);
table.setBorderWidth(0);
table.setBorder(0);
table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(0);
table.setOffset(5);
Cell secondCell = new Cell(new Phrase("", new Font(bf2, 9)));
table.addCell(secondCell);
secondCell = new Cell(new Phrase("Global Export Control ", new Font(bf2,  9)));
secondCell.setBackgroundColor(new Color(0xC1, 0xC0, 0xC0));
secondCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
secondCell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
secondCell.setLeading(9);
table.addCell(secondCell);//Line no 1675
```

Stack trace :

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.events.PdfPageEventForwarder.onEndPage(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.jar:?]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.newPage(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.jar:?]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.carriageReturn(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.jar:?]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.add(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.jar:?]
    at com.ocr.pcs.action.ProductRequestPdf$ProductRequestPage2.onEndPage(ProductRequestPdf.java:1675) ~[?:?]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.events.PdfPageEventForwarder.onEndPage(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.jar:?]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.newPage(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.jar:?]
```

Comment: Are you sure of the error line ? The stack doesn't show anything about an `addCell` call.

Comment: The exception is happening at line 1675                                                                 at com.ocr.pcs.action.ProductRequestPdf$ProductRequestPage2.onEndPage(ProductRequestPdf.java:1675) ~[?:?]                                                                       and line 1675 is table.addCell(secondCell);

Comment: According to your stack trace you use `PdfDocument.add` in an `onEndPage` page event. This is forbidden (read many stack overflow answers here on that topic) and also not sensible: A new page often is started when the current page is full as far as its main content area is concerned; if the current page is full, why would you add anything to its main content?

Comment: *"line 1675 is table.addCell(secondCell)"* - according to your stack trace that is not the case, the stack trace says that in line 1675 the `add` method of a `PdfDocument` is called (which is forbidden, see above). Thus, you additionally appear to have a different version of the code in use than you expect.

Comment: Do you see the `at com.lowagie.text.pdf`? My name is Lowagie, and you are using software I once wrote. Do you see `itext-2.1.7.jar`? That means that you are using a version of iText that dates from 2009. [That version should no longer be used!](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5) Please inform your employer that **it is not an option to continue using that version.** Tell your employer that **an upgrade is needed.** You will do yourself a service by doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you creating a new page with this code ? Your table fits the page and have an offset, try to make it a bit less than the page

- onEndPage : create a new page
- process new page : nothing
- new page onEndPage : create a new page
- process new page : nothing
- new page onEndPage : create a new page
- process new page : nothing
- new page onEndPage : create a new page
- etc, etc, etc StackOverflowError